# read file and write to file in table

Tags: php

Im trying to read a small piece of a sites code, http://www.site.com/category

And the piece of code i want to locate looks like this:

```
<div class="Brands">
    <h2>Search design</h2>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column first">
            <div>
                <a href="/category?Brand=flash">flash</a>
                <span>(9)</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="/category?Brand=bolt">bolt</a>
                <span>(4)</span> And so on...
```

What i want to do is to read the a href adress and before that put the name in a table with 2columns.
Ex

flash  wwwsitecom/category?Brand=flash 
bolt  wwwsitecom//category?Brand=bolt

I have tried several different ways but cant quite solve it.

```
<?php
$search = 'columns';
$lines = file('http://www.site.com/category');

// Store true text found
$found = false;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
        $found = true;
        echo $line;
    }
}

// text not found
if (!$found) {
    echo 'No match found';
}
?>
```

that gives me a list of the brands, but after every brand i want the pages direct link to show.

Any ideas how i could add that function?

Comment: What do you mean by "before that" ? The easiest way to do this would be to create an associative array as you parse the website content, and write later from your array.

Comment: I have edited my question, bare in mind that i am new to php. =)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the way you started to parse the file, line by line, but **you've to be sure the format won't change**. This should give you an associative array like (BRAND => LINK).

I used explode() as it wasn't that hard with the HTML pattern you gave, but a few adjustments might be needed if not all link are following this pattern (/category?Brand=flash&key=value would work for example).

Give a look at how to use regular expressions if it becomes more complex.

```
foreach($lines as $line)
{
  if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
  {
    $found = true;
    $tmp = explode ('<div>', $line); // -> <a href="/category?Brand=flash">flash</a><span>(9)</span></div>
    $count = count ($tmp);
    for ($i = 1; $count - 1; ++$i) {
      $tmp_href = explode ("\"", $tmp[$i]); // -> $tmp_href[1] = wanted href
      $tmp_brand = explode ('=', $tmp_href); // -> $tmp_brand[1] = wanted brand
      $brand_array[$tmp_brand[1]] = 'http://www.site.com' . $tmp_href[1];
    }
  }
}
```

If you want something **way more reliable**, or if you are going to parse a lot of HTML files to get links, brands, etc ... you should try to find a good library to parse HTML files. There are tons of libraries doing it.